# Make two tables side by side

Tags: html, css

I can't place two tables side by side. I have tried using negative margin. If I float left, it does not display as intended when the html page is converted to pdf.

```css
html,body{
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size:12px;
 margin:0;
    height:297mm;
    width:210mm;
}
.wrapper{
 margin: 10px 0 10px 0; 
}
.header{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}
.image{
  float: left;
  width:15%;
  margin-left:5%;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
.image img{
 margin-top:10px;
 height:99px;
 width:99px;
}
.headline{
 margin-top:15px;
 font-size:30px;
 font-weight:bold;
 float: left;
 width:100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.tagline{
 font-size:15px !important;
 font-weight: regular;
 font-style:italic;
 margin-top: 5px;
}
.table_wrapper{
 /*padding:0 5%;*/
 border: 2px solid #000;
 float:left;
 margin:15px;
}

.student_info table{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 /*float: left;*/
 padding: 15px;
   
} 
.student_info table,.student_info th,.student_info td,
.remark table,.remark th,.remark td
{
    border: 0px solid #000 !important;
}

.subject{
 width:150px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 text-align: left;
}

.score{
 width:40px;
}

.remark{
 margin-bottom:30px;
 line-height:2;
}

.student_info table tr td img{
 height:100px;
 width:80px;
 float: right;
}

.tag_bold{
 font-weight: bold;
}
.chartz{
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: green;
}
.chartz table td{
 height:14px;  
}
 .chartz table{
 height:20px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.chartz table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.txt_rotate{
  /*-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); *//* IE 9 */
    /*-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);*/ /* Safari 3-8 */
    /*transform: rotate(-90deg);*/
 padding: 50px 0;
}
.mark_chart{
 /*float:left;*/
 padding-right: 10px;
 width: 50%;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;
 background-color: blue;
 margin-right: -800px;
}
.txt_colr{
 color: #5151FF;
}
.txt_colr_red{
 color:red;
}
.txt_colr_green{
 color: green;
}
.head_title{
 font-size: 8px;
 padding: 40px 0 !important;
}
.social_chart{
 width: 20%;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
 background-color: red;
 /*float: left;*/
 margin-right: -800px;
}
.social{
 padding:43px 0;
 text-align:center;
 }
.mark_chart table{
 width:100%;
}
.social_chart table{
 width:100%;
}
.habit_chart, .behaviour_chart, .class_chart{
 padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.remark{
 float: left;
 margin-left:2%;
 width:100%;
}
.remark table{
 width:90%;
}
.footer{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 margin: 30px 0;
 font-weight: bold;
}

@media all {
 .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}

@media print {
 .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

```html
 <div class="chartz">
    <div class="mark_chart">
     <table>
       <tr style="font-weight: bold;"><td rowspan="2" class="head_title"><h1>SUBJECT TITLE</h1></td><td class="txt_rotate">1st Test</td><td class="txt_rotate">2nd Test</td><td class="txt_rotate">Exam Score</td><td class="txt_rotate">Total Score</td><td rowspan="2" class="txt_rotate">Letter Grade</td><td rowspan="2" class="txt_rotate">Subject Position</td><td class="head_title" rowspan="2"><h3>Remark</h3></td></tr>
       <tr style="font-weight: bold;" ><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>70</td><td>100</td></tr>
       <tr><td colspan="8">COGNITIVE REPORT</td></tr>
       
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>        
     </table>  
    </div>

    <div class="social_chart">
     <div class="habit_chart">
      <table>
        <tr class="tag_bold head_title">
         <td colspan="2" class="social"> <strong>SOCIAL BEHAVIOUR AND<br> MANIPULATIVE SKILLS</strong>  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tag_bold"><td>Work Habit</td><td>Ratings</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. Creativity</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>2. Industrious </td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>3. Work Independently</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>4. Follow Instructions</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>5. Neatness/Neat Work</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>6. Handwriting</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>7. Verbal Fluency</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>8. Work with Supervision</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>9. Class Participation</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>10. Work on time</td><td></td> </tr> 
      </table>
     </div>

     <div class="behaviour_chart">
      <table>
        <tr class="tag_bold"><td>Behaviour</td><td>Ratings</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. Honesty</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>2. Humility </td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>3. Self Control</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>4. Politeness</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>5. Teachers Respect</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>6. Friendliness</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>7. Punctuality</td><td></td> </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
     <div class="class_chart">
      <table>
        <tr class="tag_bold"><td colspan="2">Class Average</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Highest Class Average</td><td class="txt_colr_green">{{@$highAverage->average}}%</td> </tr>
        <tr><td>Lowest Class Average</td><td class="txt_colr_red">{{@$lowAverage->average}}%</td> </tr>    
      </table>
     </div>
     <div class="resume_chart">
      <table >
        <tr class="tag_bold"><td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">School Resumes</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">Sunday, 22 April, 2018</td> </tr>
         
      </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but this might be the solution that you are looking for

You must have to increase size of the body and change float values in css along with the margins

```css
 
.wrapper{
 margin: 10px 0 10px 0; 
}
.header{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}
.image{
  float: left;
  width:15%;
  margin-left:5%;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
.image img{
 margin-top:10px;
 height:99px;
 width:99px;
}
.headline{
 margin-top:15px;
 font-size:30px;
 font-weight:bold;
 float: left;
 width:100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.tagline{
 font-size:15px !important;
 font-weight: regular;
 font-style:italic;
 margin-top: 5px;
}
.table_wrapper{
 /*padding:0 5%;*/
 border: 2px solid #000;
 float:left;
 margin:15px;
}

.student_info table{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 /*float: left;*/
 padding: 15px;
   
} 
.student_info table,.student_info th,.student_info td,
.remark table,.remark th,.remark td
{
    border: 0px solid #000 !important;
}

.subject{
 width:150px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 text-align: left;
}

.score{
 width:40px;
}

.remark{
 margin-bottom:30px;
 line-height:2;
}

.student_info table tr td img{
 height:100px;
 width:80px;
 float: right;
}

.tag_bold{
 font-weight: bold;
}
.chartz{
 padding: 5px;
 width: 100%;
}
.chartz table td{
 height:14px;  
}
 .chartz table{
 height:20px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.chartz table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.txt_rotate{
  /*-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); *//* IE 9 */
    /*-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);*/ /* Safari 3-8 */
    /*transform: rotate(-90deg);*/
 padding: 50px 0;
}
.mark_chart{
 /*float:left;*/
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;
 background-color: blue;
 margin-right: -800px;
}
.txt_colr{
 color: #5151FF;
}
.txt_colr_red{
 color:red;
}
.txt_colr_green{
 color: green;
}
.head_title{
 font-size: 8px;
 padding: 40px 0 !important;
}
.social_chart{
 width: 50%;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
 background-color: red;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 50%;
}
.social{
 padding:43px 0;
 text-align:center;
 }
.mark_chart table{
 width:100%;
}
.social_chart table{
 width:100%;
}
.habit_chart, .behaviour_chart, .class_chart{
 padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.remark{
 float: left;
 margin-left:2%;
 width:100%;
}
.remark table{
 width:90%;
}
.footer{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 margin: 30px 0;
 font-weight: bold;
}

@media all {
 .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}

@media print {
 .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
 <style>
html,body{
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size:12px;
 margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="chartz">
    <div class="mark_chart">
     <table>
       <tbody><tr style="font-weight: bold;"><td rowspan="2" class="head_title"><h1>SUBJECT TITLE</h1></td><td class="txt_rotate">1st Test</td><td class="txt_rotate">2nd Test</td><td class="txt_rotate">Exam Score</td><td class="txt_rotate">Total Score</td><td rowspan="2" class="txt_rotate">Letter Grade</td><td rowspan="2" class="txt_rotate">Subject Position</td><td class="head_title" rowspan="2"><h3>Remark</h3></td></tr>
       <tr style="font-weight: bold;"><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>70</td><td>100</td></tr>
       <tr><td colspan="8">COGNITIVE REPORT</td></tr>
       
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="subject">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_green"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td class="txt_colr_red"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
       </tr>        
     </tbody></table>  
    </div>

    <div class="social_chart">
     <div class="habit_chart">
      <table>
        <tbody><tr class="tag_bold head_title">
         <td colspan="2" class="social"> <strong>SOCIAL BEHAVIOUR AND<br> MANIPULATIVE SKILLS</strong>  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tag_bold"><td>Work Habit</td><td>Ratings</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. Creativity</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>2. Industrious </td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>3. Work Independently</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>4. Follow Instructions</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>5. Neatness/Neat Work</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>6. Handwriting</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>7. Verbal Fluency</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>8. Work with Supervision</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>9. Class Participation</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>10. Work on time</td><td></td> </tr> 
      </tbody></table>
     </div>

     <div class="behaviour_chart">
      <table>
        <tbody><tr class="tag_bold"><td>Behaviour</td><td>Ratings</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. Honesty</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>2. Humility </td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>3. Self Control</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>4. Politeness</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>5. Teachers Respect</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>6. Friendliness</td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>7. Punctuality</td><td></td> </tr>
      </tbody></table>
     </div>
     <div class="class_chart">
      <table>
        <tbody><tr class="tag_bold"><td colspan="2">Class Average</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Highest Class Average</td><td class="txt_colr_green">{{@$highAverage-&gt;average}}%</td> </tr>
        <tr><td>Lowest Class Average</td><td class="txt_colr_red">{{@$lowAverage-&gt;average}}%</td> </tr>    
      </tbody></table>
     </div>
     <div class="resume_chart">
      <table>
        <tbody><tr class="tag_bold"><td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">School Resumes</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">Sunday, 22 April, 2018</td> </tr>
         
      </tbody></table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It's too large your code to read.

But ensure that you have structured your table correctly.

try with bellow structure and apply `CSS` where ever necessary :)

```html
<html>
<body>

<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
     <th>Table-1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>td-1</td>
     <td>td-2</td>
     <td>td-3</td>
     <td>td-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>td-5</td>
     <td>td-6</td>
     <td>td-7</td>
     <td>td-8</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
  

  <td>
   <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
     <th>Table-2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>td-1</td>
     <td>td-</td>
     <td>td-3</td>
     <td>td-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>td-5</td>
     <td>td-6</td>
     <td>td-7</td>
     <td>td-8</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>

 </tr>
<table> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code,

try adding the following property to class="chartz"

**display : flex;**

This will not only bring the tables parallel to each other but will adjust the height as well.

Comment: If the problem is not resolved, I request you to provide a link to jsfiddle where we can work on the code and resolve it.